# Error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions in long equation

Tags: matlab, debugging

I've been stuck on this error for quite a while and think I'm missing something simple. The error is in the code below (which I haven't shown as code as it will all appear as one line and I thought this may be easier to view). I am very sorry for the length of the equation, the simplify function in MATLAB did not help to reduce the size much. All the matrices are of size 1 x 300 and `W` and `Y` are scalars. However, I seem to get the Error: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions`.

```
X1n = (A12(1,:).^2.*A1S13(1,:).*W + A13(1,:).^2.*A1S12(1,:).*Y -  ...
       A12(1,:).*A13(1,:).*A1S12(1,:).*W - A11(1,:).*A22(1,:).*A1S13(1,:).*W + ...
       A11(1,:).*A23(1,:).*A1S12(1,:).*W - A12(1,:).*A23(1,:).*A1S11(1,:).*W + ...
       A13(1,:)*A22(1,:).*A1S11(1,:).*W - A12(1,:).*A13(1,:).*A1S13(1,:).*Y + ...
       A11(1,:).*A23(1,:).*A1S13(1,:).*Y - A13(1,:).*A23(1,:).*A1S11(1,:).*Y - ...
       A11(1,:).*A33(1,:).*A1S12(1,:).*Y + A12(1,:).*A33(1,:).*A1S11(1,:).*Y + ...
       A23(1,:).^2.*A1S11(1,:).*W.*Y - A12(1,:).*A23(1,:).*A1S13(1,:).*W.*Y + ...
       A13(1,:).*A22(1,:).*A1S13(1,:).*W.*Y - ...
       A13(1,:).*A23(1,:).*A1S12(1,:).*W.*Y + ...
       A12(1,:).*A33(1,:).*A1S12(1,:).*W.*Y - ...
       A22(1,:).*A33(1,:).*A1S11(1,:).*W.*Y)./(Y.*(A33(1,:).*A12(1,:).^2 - ...
       2*A12(1,:).*A13(1,:).*A23(1,:) + ...
       A22(1,:).*A13(1,:).^2 + A11(1,:).*A23(1,:).^2 - ...
       A11(1,:).*A22(1,:).*A33(1,:)))
```

Comment: Check out Matlab's option on how to [continue long statements on  multiple lines](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/continue-long-statements-on-multiple-lines.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your error (line 4):

```
A13(1,:)*A22(1,:)
```

Change it to:

```
A13(1,:).*A22(1,:)
```

Comment: Good catch! I didn't notice that at all.